# Problem installing Visio in parallel to MS Office Pro 2016 despite using ODT

Tags: installation, visio

I receive the messade "Click-to-Run and Windows Installer on same computer isn't supported" when trying to installing Visio in parallel to MS Office Pro 2016.
I get the same message even when running the ODT from the command prompt:
setup.exe /configure  configuration.xml
where configuration.xml 
contains the specified code:

```
<Configuration>
    <Add OfficeClientEdition="64" >
        <Product ID="VisioProXVolume" PIDKEY="69WXN-MBYV6-22PQG-3WGHK-RM6XC">
             <Language ID="en-us" />
        </Product>
    </Add>  
</Configuration>
```

Any further suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Your Office 2016 installation seems to be MSI (Microsoft Installer) based and your Visio 2016 setup C2R (Click 2 Run) based.

That mixup is not supported by Microsoft.

You would need to have both MSI or C2R setups.

This 'workaround' by using ODT seems to be only possible when trying to install an MSI version of Visio/Project next to a C2R Version of Office, if I understood it correctly. But I never used it yet at all.

Its really a pity.

See here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/office-installed-with-click-to-run-and-windows-installer-on-same-computer-isn-t-supported-30775ef4-fa77-4f47-98fb-c5826a6926cd

Comment: It seems poor that Microsoft cannot solve this "own-goal" problem. As an "ex-system engineer" who took great efforts to isolate users from internal problems, I have difficulty in comprehending the problem.